# Webpack package 4.41.2 security issue because terser-webpack-plugin which uses serialize-javascript version 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am facing below issue, because of a webpack internal dependency "serialize-javascript" version:1.9.1

webpack version 4.41.2 using terser-webpack-plugin and it uses serialize-javascript version 1.9.1

and now github alerting the same issue for my project.

what can i do ?

[security issue github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI1EH.png)

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by re-installing webpack: https://github.com/ryanbrookepayne/inline-calculator/commit/76554b1efc42bea47d59a3ff9fc7606dbf211c52

Answer (score 4):

If using yarn, you can use [resolutions](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/):

```
"resolutions": {
  "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.4.2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was patched 3 days ago on https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/releases/tag/v1.4.2.
Just add the following to your package.json under "dependencies", and/or "devDependencies", and run "npm install". Double check that your package-lock.json is updated.

```
"devDependencies": {
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.4.2",
        "serialize-javascript": ">=2.1.1",
}
```

Note that webpack depends on "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.4.1". So changing to 1.4.2 is [fine](https://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/).